# Delete milions of records from a table sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with 2.4 billion records and I need to delete approx 500 million records from that table using some filter.

This is my query so far:

```
SET ROWCOUNT 1000
delete_more:
DELETE FROM hwbss..tblsdr WHERE dst <= 123456444
IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0 GOTO delete_more
SET ROWCOUNT 0
```

It takes a lot of time in record deletion.

What is the problem and how can I speed up deletion.

Comment: Do you have indexes and constraints on that table? It might be a good idea to disable/drop those, then do the delete, and afterwards re-enable / re-create them again. But deleting **that much data** just WILL take some time!

Answer (score 0):

First thing is to set your database recovery model to simple.

```
ALTER DATABASE Database Name
SET RECOVERY SIMPLE
```

Delete operation logs details for each and very row and hence takes more time as the logs keep on growing.

Then, disable the constraints and indexes, if any on the table. You can rebuild the indexes once the deletion operation is completed.

**Alternate Approach:**

You can also insert the data from existing table except 500 M records into a new table with same name as existing table but, in a different schema e.g. `Tmp.TableName`. You can then drop  the existing table and alter the schema of Tmp table using

```
ALTER SCHEMA [SchemaName]
TRANSFER [Tmp].[TableName]
```

Comment: Some of this is factually incorrect. Every data operation is written to the log whether using full or simple recovery. The difference is when the log records can be reused and prevention of growing the log file unnecessarily. Also, check if a full backup is required to truly make the new recovery model take effect.

Comment: Yes, you should take a full or differential backup of your database before setting the recovery mode to simple. This is because after setting the recovery mode to simple, the transaction logs that are stored in .ldf file are truncated when a specific limit is reached. So, it is only possible to recover the database till the last full/ differential backup in case of simple recovery model. This is not a pre-requisite but, its better to do it to avoid any data loss in case of failure. After deletion, you can set the recovery mode to full using ALTER DATABASE Database Name SET RECOVERY FULL

Comment: Yes, that's true. The log is written but, it is eventually truncated.